# Get list count then update header in listview

Tags: android, listview

I have 2 xml files

`Header` and `Section`

then i use some condition to segregate those two and the output of that is this

```
|8/2/2018|
----------
 Data 1
 Data 2
|8/2/2018|
----------
 Data 1
 Data 2
 Data 3
```

It is a listview that groups data with same date and the 1 date header for them.
My question is how can I count each data then update the header? like this

```
|8/2/2018 (2)|
----------
 Data 1
 Data 2
|8/2/2018 (3)|
----------
 Data 1
 Data 2
 Data 3
```

Im using `Listview` and `ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter`

where do i will update?

here

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View v = convertView;
            ItemModel cell = (ItemModel) getItem(position);

   if (cell.isSectionHeader()) {
        //Display Date in Header XML
   } else {
        //Display in Section XML
   }
}
```

or here

```
private ArrayList sortAndAddSections(ArrayList<ItemModel> itemList) {

        ArrayList<ItemModel> tempList = new ArrayList<>();
        Collections.sort(itemList);

        String header = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < itemList.size(); i++) {
            if (!(header.equals(itemList.get(i).getDate()))) {
                String data = itemList.get(i).getRemarks();
                String date = itemList.get(i).getDate()
                ItemModel sectionCell = new ItemModel(date,data);
                sectionCell.setToSectionHeader();
                tempList.add(sectionCell);
                header = itemList.get(i).getDate();
            }

            tempList.add(itemList.get(i));
        }
        return tempList;
    }
```

Updated

Here is how I transfer the data from database to array

```
private ArrayList<ItemModel> getItems() {
        Cursor data = myDb.get_plan(email);
        ArrayList<ItemModel> items = new ArrayList<>();
        while (data.moveToNext()) {
            String date = data.getString(3);
            String data1 = data.getString(4);
            items.add(new ItemModel(date,data1));
        }
        return items;
    }
```

then this where the condition goes

```
private ArrayList sortAndAddSections(ArrayList<ItemModel> itemList) {

        ArrayList<ItemModel> tempList = new ArrayList<>();

        String header = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < itemList.size(); i++) {
            if (!(header.equals(itemList.get(i).getDate()))) {
                String date = itemList.get(i).getDate();
                String getData1 = itemList.get(i).getData1();
                ItemModel sectionCell = new ItemModel(date,data1);
                sectionCell.setToSectionHeader();
                tempList.add(sectionCell);
                header = itemList.get(i).getDate();
            }
            tempList.add(itemList.get(i));
        }
        return tempList;
    }
```

this is where i set it in textview

```
@Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View v = convertView;
            ItemModel cell = (ItemModel) getItem(position);

            if (cell.isSectionHeader()) {
                v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.section_header, null);
                v.setClickable(false);
                TextView header = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.list_date);
                header.setText(cell.getDate());
            } else {
                v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_plan, null);
                TextView tv_data1 = v.findViewById(R.id.list_data1);
                tv_cusname.setText(cell.getData1());
            }

            return v;
        }
```

Comment: Please add the code where you setting the text of the header.

Comment: updated my post

Comment: i tried this last night. too hard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
    private ArrayList sortAndAddSections(ArrayList<ItemModel> itemList) {

    ArrayList<ItemModel> tempList = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Integer> tmpHeaderPositions = new ArrayList<>(); // Added

    String header = "";

    ItemModel sectionCell; // Changed
    int addedRow = 0; // Edited 
    for (int i = 0; i < itemList.size(); i++) {
        if (!(header.equals(itemList.get(i).getDate()))) {
            String date = itemList.get(i).getDate();
            String getData1 = itemList.get(i).getData1();
            sectionCell = new ItemModel(date,data1); // Changed
            sectionCell.setToSectionHeader();
            tmpHeaderPositions.add(i + addedRow); // Edited
            addedRow++; // Edited
            tempList.add(sectionCell);
            header = itemList.get(i).getDate();
        }
        tempList.add(itemList.get(i));
    }

    // Added this code block
    tmpHeaderPositions.add(tempList.size());
    for (int i = 0; i < tmpHeaderPositions.size() - 1; i++) {
        sectionCell = tempList.get(tmpHeaderPositions.get(i));
        sectionCell.setDate(sectionCell.getDate() + "(" +
                (tmpHeaderPositions.get(i + 1) - tmpHeaderPositions.get(i) - 1) + ")");
    }

    return tempList;
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: tysm, I will try it

Comment: where i can put the total count? because it gave me double textview on output although it is working

Comment: sorry just a wrong code on my part anyways it work. tysm

Comment: it has a problem. if i added new date the counter doesnt show

Comment: the total is less than 1 based on row

Comment: sir its working but data shows only on the 1st header and total count is -1 (record is 6 but the value 5)

Comment: Edited the answer! Please note the 3 lines with Edited comment.

Comment: it is now fix. TYSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSMM :)

Comment: sir i have a question

Comment: Another problem??

Answer (score 0):

You can setText later when you get the list of data and then with the help of arraylist.length() you can set the text into section.

Comment: can you spare me some time and give some hint code for it?

Comment: The place where you are grouping data fields according to the date, there you can add each data field into an ArrayList. and then update the header with the count.

Comment: to hard to visualize. sorry :(

Comment: If you could share your code, I'll fix that for you.

Comment: any feedback mate?